# How to prevent a user from entering the site using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

To put it in a nushell, i want to prevent a user from entering when variable in this table in Activity equels 1: https://ibb.co/hhjU0q. 
HTML table: https://ibb.co/cc190q. So when you click on checkbox and Delete, Activity variable should equal 1 from 0, and user can't log in the site, but his string in HTML table is preserved, that is, it does not disappear, and the value 'blocked' appears in the Status column. So when Activity equals 0, user can enter the site, when 1 - he can't. The problem is that how to connect a checkbox with a string of user in HTML table. PHP code:

```
<button> Block </button>   
<button onclick="selectAll(this)"> Select All</button> 
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Last login</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
<?php 
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');
$query = "SELECT*FROM users WHERE Activity = 0";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die (mysqli_error($db));
for ( $data = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $data[] = $row );
$result='';
foreach ($data as $elem) 
{
  $result.='<tr>';
      $result.='<td><input type="checkbox"></td>';
      $result.='<td>'.$elem['username'].'</td>';
      $result.='<td>'.$elem['lastlogin'].'</td>';
      $result.='<td>'.$elem['Activity'].'</td>';
  $result.='</tr>';
}
echo $result;
?>
</table>
```

Thanks for any idea and help!)

Comment: Which part of your code is supposed to "prevent" user from accessing your site?

Comment: this is just an HTMLl table code

Comment: Nothing seems kind of insertion in your code.